# Email Input - Name Input

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

Below I put an email input that I use in SharePoint and it's very inefficient to have to search for the names the way it currently does. Lets say I have used this name before and I want it to show up a dialog box below to click for easy use. Kind of like Outlook Emails work....is this possible?

[image: Email - Name Input]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll need something that's not out of the box.

Here's a breakdown of what I believe is needed:

- custom javascript that will provide "autocomplete" feature (custom ajax, angular, etc)
- a place to store/access the last used emails for the autocomplete to use(sharepoint list,sharepoint view, browser localstorage, 3rd party db, etc)

the javascript will need to talk back to sharepoint using CSOM.

There is other ways of getting this, a custom built wsp etc. but I favor CSOM since that's the direction sharepoint customizations appear to be going in order to maintain compatibility with sharepoint online services.

Comment: He tagged it ``infopath``... do all these CSOM goodies work?

Comment: If this form is being presented on sharepoint, then it should work the same way. a custom javascript needs to be loaded from sharepoint master template. the infopath form is displayed within the master template, as long as your javascript is targetting the right form field, it can add extra functionality. The only concern is, without a proof of concept, there is a possible chance there is javascript conflict with the out-of-the-box user selection and our custom autocomplete.

Comment: As someone who is fairly new to SharePoint I'm really interested into out-of-the-box ideas. I'm going to try to input a JavaScript form that will store previously used input for certain fields. Thanks for all the help!